# How to update dictionaries inside of two nested lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 nested list here:

```py
l1 = [{'v1':'abc', 'v2':20}, {'v1':'bcd', 'v2':30}, {'v1':'egf', 'v2':15}]
l2 = [{'v1':'abc', 'v3':25}, {'v1':'bcd', 'v3':10}]
```

I need to update `l1` dicts for the additional key `v3` based on the match of `v1` on both the dicts in the list with end result as:

```py
[{'v1':'abc', 'v2':20,'v3':25}, {'v1':'bcd', 'v2':30, 'v3':10}, {'v1':'egf', 'v2':15}]
```

You can easily do it by using nested for loops -

```
    for i in d1:
      for j in d2:
         if d2[j]['v1'] == d1[i]['v1']:
            d1[i]['v3'] = d2[j]['v3']
            break
```

Is there any more pythonic way to solve this problem? Like using enum and avoiding nested for loops?

Comment: `d1`, `d2` and the output are invalid data structures. Are they lists of dicts?

Comment: Yes, they are. updated it

Comment: More pythonic and less time complexity. Avoid n^2 algorithm unless we have no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Naming the lists as `d1` and `d2` makes them a little confusing. So, I took the liberty of renaming them as `l1`, `l2`, and the resulting list as `l3`. You can use list comprehension with dictionary update syntax like this:

```py
l1 = [{"v1": "abc", "v2": 20}, {"v1": "bcd", "v2": 30}]
l2 = [{"v1": "abc", "v3": 25}, {"v1": "bcd", "v3": 10}]

[{"v1": "abc", "v2": 20, "v3": 25}, {"v1": "bcd", "v2": 30, "v3": 10}]

# List comp with ** syntax to update the dicts of the first list
l3 = [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(l1, l2)]

print(l3)
```

This will print:

```
[{'v1': 'abc', 'v2': 20, 'v3': 25}, {'v1': 'bcd', 'v2': 30, 'v3': 10}]
```

*N.B. As pointed out by [@Asocia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9608759/asocia), this solution has one caveat. It assumes the lists to be sorted as you've provided in the problem statement.*

Comment: This would fail if the `l2` list is not sorted. Try running it after `l2 = list(reversed(l2))` and output will change.

Comment: That is true. However, the OP didn't give any additional information regarding edge-cases and whatnot. This seems to be the most straightforward way to do it if the lists are already sorted as provided in the problem.

Comment: Actually you are right. Upvoted for the simplicity.

Comment: thanks @RedowanDelowar But this will not work if the list l1 have a different length than the list l2, even if it is sorted. I am updating this scenario in my question